# mod_rewrite Replace dashes with underscores in subdomain then redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is what i want to do:

- I want to replace all dashes (-) with underscores (_) but only in subdomains.
- After all dashes are replaced i want to redirect into a subdirectory with the name of the rewritten subdomain

For example: 
http://subdomain-with-dashes.rotarytest.de/a-directory/an-image.png
after rewrite should be
http://rotarytest.de/subdomain_with_dashes/a-directory/an-image.png

Here is what i have right now, please see comments in code

```
RewriteEngine on

# replace dashes with underscores
# this works, but only for the last dash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)-(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1_%2/$1 [L,R=301]


# if a subdomain is called, redirect to subdirectory
# this code works but only when i have one dash in my subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.rotarytest\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rotarytest.de/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I tried almost every solution i found here on stackoverflow or on the web, but none of them worked correctly.

Can someone help me out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the point of this, when rule 3 would just redirect this subdomain to the mydomain.de/subdomain-name?

Comment: As you can see in my comment below, i first want to replace the dashes with underscores, and then redirect the rewritten subdomain to a folder: http://mydomain.de/subdomain_previously_with_dashes/a-directory/an-image.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow the browser to continually redirect to remove the dashes. If you don't need the dashes to be replaced with underscores in the URI, then you don't want the first two rules, they don't get applied to the hostname. Replace the first two rules with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)-(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1_%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That only works partly. The dash IS replaced with an underscore, but my following rules should be applied to that rewritten URI, so that i get http://mydomain.de/subdomain_previously_with_dashes/a-directory/an-image.png. So i removed the L Tag on your rule, but then the dashes aren´t replaced.